# Pandas -- filling pandas column with random normal variable with mean from another column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have data that looks like this:

```
Mean
4.5
5.6
3.5
6.7
```

What I would like to do is uses `np.random.normal()` to build a random normal variable using the mean column that produces something like this (obviously, the random numbers will be different everytime):

```
Mean  RV
4.5   6.2
5.6   3.1
3.5   4.3
6.7   5.6
```

I tried something like this:
`df['RV'] = np.random.normal(df['Mean'], 3.2, 1)`

but was unsuccessful. Maybe a `lambda` would be useful here? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Using `np.random.normal` directly to take advantage of numpy's vector operations is much faster than using panda's `apply` function:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Mean': np.arange(0., 1000000., 1.),
        'StdDev': np.arange(0., 1000000., 1.)/1000000. + 1.,
})

df['RV'] = np.random.normal(loc=df['Mean'], scale=df['StdDev'])
```

For a dataframe with 1M rows, this approach runs in about 60ms on my computer, vs 2 seconds for the apply approach, i.e. about 30x faster.

I don't see any reason why this would not have worked in your case.

Answer (score 1):

You could apply [`np.random.normal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) along the values of the Series, using each value as the mean of the normal distribution. Updated the code with @jpp suggestion, as using a `lambda` function is not necessary here given that the mean is the first parameter the function takes:

```
import numpy as np
df.assign(RV= df.Mean.apply(np.random.normal))

    Mean        RV
0   4.5  5.743574
1   5.6  4.910578
2   3.5  1.853348
3   6.7  7.061648
```

Comment: Thanks, guys. Using lambda actually worked best for me so that I could add the standard deviation parameter to np.random.normal

Answer (score 1):

Pass column to [`np.random.normal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) for increase performance:

```
df['RV'] = np.random.normal(df['Mean'])
print (df)
   Mean        RV
0   4.5  4.138135
1   5.6  6.285609
2   3.5  4.073761
3   6.7  6.987728
```

Comment: what if a column with random normal distribution with mean 0.3 and range 0 to 1